# Web forms ClientIDMode default changed in IIS8 - how to get back to good old aspnetForm?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Let's be clear, I don't really like WebForms. Which is why I do not wish to spend hours debugging a legacy code base that ran perfectly well on one server (IIS7) and a new one (IIS8).

I heard there is this new `ClientIDMode`, which makes forms and other controls change their IDs or not to something sensible, but I didn't touch it. It seems like the default value has changed (ie is not backwards compatible)?

I had a form in a master page that looked like `<form id=SiteForm runat=server`

This automatically changed its ID to `aspnetForm` in the rendered output.

Sure it was a bit weird, but I have a lot of code in this app that relies on it. I could simply change the ID in the server page to `<form id=SiteForm runat=aspnetForm` and that might fix it. But maybe there's some code in this old project that uses `SiteForm` on the server side, so I can search for that.

But there could be other controls lurking around which had their IDs changed too. So maybe there is something I can add to the web config to turn the behaviour back to what it was before? What was the default before?

UPDATE: Looks like when exporting and importing the app pools this site somehow got changed from .NET2 to .NET4, so perhaps I just need to set it back to .NET2?

Comment: Have you tried adding `<pages clientIDMode="Predictable" />` in your web.config file? The property `clientIDMode` defines how IDs are generated.

Comment: I didnt actually try that, because i wanted some advice of any gotchas before going down the road of debugging it. But that might work.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had not ticked the box to install .NET 3.5 within IIS setup. This is why all my app pools reverted to .NET 4 automatically and why these weird changes happened. So I installed it in IIS, restarted, and set the app pool to .NET 2 (ie 3.5). This fixed it, cleanly, so I will call that the solution.